# Software to control mobile phone via bluetooth

Tags: linux, bluetooth, mobile-phone

I'm looking for some software that will allow me to control a mobile phone via Bluetooth. I'm using Linux as my OS, but I can use something else if need be.

Specifically, I'd like to be able to do the following from software running on my computer

1. Enter a number and have the mobile phone dial it.
2. Use my computer's headphone/microphone jack to listen and talk on the phone.

It seems that at least #2 should be possible since a physical Bluetooth headset can be used to audio I/O to the phone.

Answer (score 1):

A program called Remote Professional from mobileways.de claims to be able to make calls from your PC-mobile(and therefore achieve partly what u wish to accomplish). There is a brief article about it entitled *Remotely Control Your Phone from Computer* from Technize.com

A youtube video and link to download the program is also included: http://www.technize.com/remotely-control-your-phone-from-computer/

Answer (score 0):

There is an android app that allows users to use their devices to control any other present android device. You must use BT controller to make your android/tablet act like a game pad controller to play a game on the emulator present on the Android OS.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using an app named AirDroid Personal, so far so good. It supports the function of making phone calls on windows, macos, linux and web. Maybe you can try it too.